# Exposing Prometheus metrics endpoint for Spring app deployed on Kubernetes actuator/prometheus Is unaccessible

Tags: spring, kubernetes, prometheus

I have a Spring app that I've deployed on Kubernetes, and I'm using Prometheus for monitoring and metrics collection. Locally, when running the app with IntelliJ, I can access the Prometheus metrics at http://localhost:8087/actuator/prometheus. However, when the app is deployed on Kubernetes, this path is no longer accessible

I added the required line in app.proprites

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true
```

and the dependecies

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

here is the deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prometheus-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prometheus-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prometheus-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: prometheus
          image: prom/prometheus:latest
          args:
            - "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
            - "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus/"

          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
          volumeMounts:
            - name: prometheus-config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/prometheus/
            - name: prometheus-storage-volume
              mountPath: /prometheus/
      volumes:
        - name: prometheus-config-volume
          configMap:
            name: prometheus-config
            items:
              - key: prometheus.yml
                path: prometheus.yml
            defaultMode: 0644
        - name: prometheus-rules-volume
          configMap:
            name: prometheus-rules
            items:
              - key: rules.rules
                path: rules/rules.rules
            defaultMode: 0644
        - name: prometheus-storage-volume
          emptyDir: {}

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: prometheus-service
spec:
  selector: 
    app: prometheus-server
  type: NodePort  
  ports:
    - port: 9090
      targetPort: 9090
      nodePort: 30000
```

this is the config yml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prometheus-config
data:
  prometheus.yml: |
    global:
      scrape_interval:     15s
      evaluation_interval: 15s
    rule_files:
      - /etc/prometheus/rules.yml
    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: 'spring'
        metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
        scrape_interval: 15s
        static_configs:
        - targets: ['10.98.84.247:8087']
```

this is the service of my deployment

```
spring-consumer-service                      LoadBalancer   10.xx.xx.xxx     localhost     8087:xxxx/TCP   20d
```